# C# Adding items to object list field

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I've two class Agens and OrdiniPuddy. There is a relationship among them by mean codAge field.

```
 public class Agens
    {
        public string COD_CG { get; set; }
        public string codAge { get; set; }
        public string Agente { get; set; }
        public string Societa { get; set; }

        public DateTime PrimaTrasm { get; set; }
        public DateTime UltimaTrasm { get; set; }

        public int Destinazioni { get; set; }
        public int Pezzi { get; set; }
        public double Imponibile { get; set; }

      public List<OrdiniPuddy> ordiniPuddy { get; set; }
    }



public class OrdiniPuddy
    {
        public string codCli { get; set; }
        public string Dest_ID { get; set; }

        public string Ragsoc { get; set; }
        public string Indirizzo { get; set; }
        public string Localita { get; set; }
        public string Prov { get; set; }
        public string Regione { get; set; }
        public string Calendario { get; set; }
        public string Cap { get; set; }
        public string codAgente { get; set; }

    }
```

I've populated them with this code:

```
var results = connection.QueryMultiple(sql);
 IEnumerable<Agens> agenti = results.Read<Agens>();
 IEnumerable<OrdiniPuddy> ordiniP = results.Read<OrdiniPuddy>();
```

Last step is to passing ordiniP to  agenti.ordiniPuddy by mean AddRange Linq method
like this

```
foreach (var item in agenti)
            {
                 
               IEnumerable <OrdiniPuddy> ordini = ordiniP.Where(o => o.codAgente == item.codAge).ToList();
                  agenti.ordiniPuddy.AddRange((IEnumerable<Agens>)ordini); 
            }
```

but the compiler give me a error message on agenti.ordiniPuddy: 'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Where is the error, why I can't referencing agenti.ordiniPuddy?
My C# knowledge are at beginning.
Thank's

Comment: I think you mean `item.ordiniPuddy.AddRange(ordini)` not `agenti.ordiniPuddy.AddRange((IEnumerable<Agens>)ordini)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your code

```
var ordini = ordiniP.Where(o => o.codAgente == item.codAge).ToList();

if(ordini!=null) 
{
 if( item.ordiniPuddy ==null)  item.ordiniPuddy=new List<OrdiniPuddy>();
item.ordiniPuddy.AddRange(ordini); 
}
```

Comment: `agenti` is currently an `IEnumerable<Agens>` and doesn't have a `ordiniPuddy` property

Comment: A small improvement: if `ordini` would be null, you'd have run into a null-ref exception on the first line. If that line passes without error, the if-condition will never evaluate to `false`. So either you should add a `?` in `ordiniP?.Where...` or the if-condition (null check) is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you are right and it is irellevant, but since it is not my code I  prefer to put extra if instead of catching exeption.

Comment: is exactly as you expected, ordersPuddy must be instantiated every new line, otherwise you have a Null reference exception. Thanks so much